# Fit as much on the x axis as possible in chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart that has times on X axes. How can I remove the gaps in between the points on the X axes? I think that it might be called interval or scale or something but I'm not sure where in the properties I can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Microsoft Chart controls and you are trying to fit the "time" labels within the XAxis length.

You can set the `LabeAutoFitStyle` property of the ChartArea's XAxis as fitted for your requirement. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.labelautofitstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN link for different LabelAutoFitStyles.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[ChartName].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep45;
```

If you want to change the intervals and number of intervals used in display, use `AxisX.Interval` and `AxisX.IntervalAutoMode` property.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - sorry for the rushed question we have a huge conference going on at the moment.